Problemas con el archivo Kernel.php en Laravel 11.22
Estoy tratando de crear una nueva forma de autenticar en mi app con un nuevo middleware, pero siguiendo el tutorial, observé que tenía un archivo llamado Kernel.php en la carpeta app/http/. Busqué ese archivo en todos lados pero no lo encontré, a alguien le ha pasado lo mismo? Pregunté a ChatGPT e intenté agregar manualmente el archivo Kernel, pero el middleware sigue sin funcionar. También intenté crear nuevos proyectos pero en ninguno me generaba el archivo kernel, tal vez sea la versión??

Desde Laravel 11, el archivo Kernel.php no existe. Ahora debes referirte a bootstrap/app.php. De la doc: The Kernel.php files are no longer in the Laravel project, and these are handled through the framework bootstrap/app.php file.

En la misma doc (enlace de mi anterior comentario) te explica cómo añadir un nuevo middleware. Agregando algo parecido a esto $middleware->web(append: \App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class); en la closure withMiddleware  del archivo bootstrap/app.php. En ese enlace están todos los cambios significativos y se explican las nuevas formas en que hay que hacer las cosas según esos cambios. Leer también las notas de la nueva versión.
